# Using CHOOSE Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone give me some example using Choose Function in SQL Server?

Have you ever used this function before? Is it useful for something?

Comment: `choose()` is a short-hand for a more complicated `case` expression.  It is useful.

Comment: I'd like to see an example

Comment: why not reference the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql) for an example? `CHOOSE (ProductCategoryID, 'A','B','C','D','E')`  product categoryID is a number 1-5.  If 1 then A if 2 then b if 3 then c etc...

Comment: I need a real case scenario to see if maybe one day I could use it and if it IS better to some sitatuations

Answer (score 2):

The syntax would be -

```
CHOOSE ( index, val_1, val_2 [, val_n ] )
```

Example -

```
SELECT CHOOSE ( 3, 'Manager', 'Director', 'Developer', 'Tester' ) AS Result;
```

More Info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql

Comment: I need an example without being like that. I want to see something more complex

Comment: I hope this helps : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019(v=sql.110).aspx